# How to merge **kwargs with pipe operator?

Tags: python, django

I have a model as below:

```py
# models.py

class Lorem(models.Model):
    # ...
    foo_bar = models.BooleanField()
    foo_baz = models.BooleanField()
    # ...
```

This model has fields such as `foo_bar` and `foo_baz`. I know I will query `Lorem` instances where `foo_bar` *or* `foo_baz` is `True` frequently in the future. So there I go create a custom `QuerySet` and add it to model [as_manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.as_manager).

```py
# models.py

class LoremQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def foo(self):
        return self.filter(models.Q(foo_bar=True) | models.Q(foo_baz=True))


class Lorem(models.Model):
    # ...
    foo_bar = models.BooleanField()
    foo_baz = models.BooleanField()
    # ...

    objects = LoremQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Up until this point, it's fine. However, in my case, I can predict I will need other fields on my `Lorem` model *in the future*, such as `foo_boo` or `foo_bee` or whatever. And any time I add these fields, I need to manually refactor `LoremQuerySet.foo()` to have all the fields.

```py
# LoremQuerySet.foo()

# ...
return self.filter(models.Q(foo_bar=True) | models.Q(foo_baz=True) | models.Q(foo_bee=True) | models.Q(foo_boo=True)) # etc
# ...
```

So, I've found a dirty workaround. I *filter* all attributes of `Lorem` starting with `foo_`.

```py
# LoremQuerySet.foo()

# ...
foo_attrs = filter(lambda s: s.startswith("foo_"), dir(Lorem)) # filter attrs starting with "lorem_"
# generator resulting in ("foo_bar", "foo_baz") etc
# ...
```

However, I'm stuck at this point. How can I merge this filter with pipe operator? How can I programmatically merge filtered `str` attributes as `Q(...) | Q(...)`?

Or, to put it more generic, how can I merge `*args` or `**kwargs` with logical operators?

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

- Python 3.8.5
- Django 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a `Q` object query up while iterating over your attrs.

```py
query = Q()

for attr in my_iterable:
    query |= Q(attr=True)
```

You can also build an `AND` query in a similar way by using `&=`

That'll result in something like;

`<Q: (OR: ('foo_bar', True), ('foo_baz', True), ('foo_bat', True))>`